# After Deleting storyboard file in Objective C I got following error message in XCode 11.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, delete-file

I created a storyboard while I developing ios project in XCode. Then I delete it. When I delete it there asked **Remove Reference** or **Move to Trash** as following screenshot.

[image: While deleting stroyboard]

There I clikcked Remove Reference. After that I got Following Errors in my Objective C project.

```
Undefined Symbol:
```

and

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_openTransactionsMultiVC_SID", referenced from:
      -[ReceiptMailViewController okBack:] in ReceiptMailViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

See Following image for more clear
[image: Errors]

Comment: You just removed any connections from the UI to your code - was there a particular reason to remove the storyboard?

Comment: What is in this `okBack` method?

Comment: @red_menace I just clicked remove reference as first pic show when I needed to delete the storyboard.

Comment: What did you have linked in the storyboard, and why are you deleting it?